# transform pandas pivot table to regular dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How can I convert a pandas pivot table to a regular dataframe ? For example:

```
                           amount                                                
categories                  A                B           C  
date         deposit                                                             
2017-01-15   6220140.00    5614354.16        0.00        0.00 
2017-01-16   7384354.00    6247300.22        0.00        0.00 
2017-01-17   6783939.00    10630021.37       0.00        0.00 
2017-01-18   67940.00      4659384.47        0.00        0.00
```

to a regular datetime such as this:

```
   date         deposit       A                 B           C                                                                         
0  2017-01-15   6220140.00    5614354.16        0.00        0.00 
1  2017-01-16   7384354.00    6247300.22        0.00        0.00 
2  2017-01-17   6783939.00    10630021.37       0.00        0.00 
3  2017-01-18   67940.00      4659384.47        0.00        0.00
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) + `index name` to `None` + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0) #remove amount
df.columns.name = None               #remove categories
df = df.reset_index()                #index to columns
```

Alternatively use [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

EDIT:

Maybe also help remove `[]` in parameter `values` - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252078/2901002).

Answer (score 21):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
```

Answer (score 4):

Was able to solve it using Reset index

```
Sample_df=df.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.columns = [f'{col[0]}_{col[1]}' if col[1] else col[0] for col in df.columns]

df.reset_index(level=df.index.names, inplace=True)

df
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. [Is there any benefit to allowing code-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques/148274#148274) *PS: you had that in the earlier version, but in Spanish, translate it and put it back in, I'd suggest*