# Dropping the sum column in pandas pivot table, but keeping the row

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a pandas pivot table and I want to keep the sum of the columns at the bottom (so the sum row). However, there is also a column that is added when I say margins=True and I don't want that.

I have tried dropping the column, but dropping a column from a multiindex table just resulted in errors. If I do drop('All', axis=1), it says KeyError: 'All', and if I do axis=0 it gets rid of the total on the bottom (which I want).

```
artist_table = pd.pivot_table(total_df,
                              values=['Records Created', 
                                      'Tickets Sold'],
                              index=['artist name',
                                     'artist id'],
                              columns=['date'],
                              aggfunc=np.sum,
                              fill_value=0,
                              margins=True)
```

What I want is:

```
                                 Leads Created       Revenue     
 date                             6/1                 6/2                                        
    artist_id    artist_name      
    XXX           YYY            x                   y            
    AAA           BBB            a                   b            
    All                         (x+a)             (y+b)
```

What I have now is:

```
                                Leads Created       Revenue     
date                              6/1                 6/2           All                                
artist_id    artist_name      
    XXX           YYY              x                   y          (x+y)
    AAA           BBB              a                   b          (a+b)
    All                           (x+a)             (y+b)
```

I would like that All on the right (the sums of the rows) to be gone. Can anyone please help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Once you've got the data in artist_table, could you use `artist_table = artist_table.drop("All", axis=1)`?

Comment: adding `.drop('All', 1)` to the right of your `pivot_table` command

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411544/delete-column-from-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Hi thank you for your response...unfortunately that didn't work. I did not put the entire table in the post, but I added it so you can better understand what I am working with.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution?  Dropping the All column is driving me crazy, and I also don't need an All row like you did.  However, if I set margins=False, it for some reason screws up my dropna=True because my resulting table shows the NAN.  I set margins=True and the NANs are gone but I get an All column I don't want.  Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

You can swap the headers level by

```
artist_table=artist_table.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

and then drop the "All" column

```
artist_table.drop("All", axis=1)
```

then you can swap the levels back

```
artist_table=artist_table.swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting Pivot Table to Dataframe using the alternative option suggested here:

[transform pandas pivot table to regular dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756052/transform-pandas-pivot-table-to-regular-dataframe)

...and then dropped the 'All' column from that new dataframe.