# Remove double row column names from a pivot result

Tags: pandas

I'd like to remove a 'double row' index header of a pivot result, so the following table:

```
Course_ID   CID-1   CID-2   CID-3
ID          
1           3.5     2.0     3.0
2           4.0     3.0     NaN
```

would look like this:

```
ID          CID-1   CID-2   CID-3           
1           3.5     2.0     3.0
2           4.0     3.0     NaN
```

How may I achieve this?

Here's the sample code:

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2], 
                       'Course_ID': ['CID-1', 'CID-2', 'CID-3', 'CID-1', 'CID-2'], 
                       'Grade': [3.5, 2, 3, 4, 3]})

result = pd.pivot_table(sample, index='ID', columns='Course_ID', values='Grade')
```

Comment: [very related to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756052/transform-pandas-pivot-table-to-regular-dataframe)

Comment: ah true, I couldn't find similar questions before I asked. Thank you @anky. Should i delete my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for remove `columns name`, here `Course_ID` and then [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for convert index to column `ID`:

```
result = result.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print (result)
   ID  CID-1  CID-2  CID-3
0   1    3.5    2.0    3.0
1   2    4.0    3.0    NaN
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do

```
result.columns.name = None
```