# Pandas Pivot - remove multi level index and set as columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Hi I am using pandas pivot functionality .

```
df1=pd.pivot_table(df, index=[week_column,'Rank_Trx'],columns='Target channel',values= [id_column],aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
```

The output I receive is something like this.
[image]

However the output i am looking for should look like this.
[image]

So the columns of the data frame I wish to have should be "Period","Rank_Trx","PDE","Samples","Take no action"
Basically I want this a NxN data frame without any multilevel index . I am using the latest pandas version 1.0.5

Comment: Found a solution to this:-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756052/transform-pandas-pivot-table-to-regular-dataframe

Comment: @Ch3steR yes it does thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the index of the dataframe with

```py
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Comment: Hi yes but with that I also need to do some more additional steps either ways found the answer and have posted it thanks.