# drop multiindex level but keep names of columns - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a `df` that looks like this

```
   a     b      c
              c1  c2
0  87    33   32  34
1  32    10   45  62
2  78    83   99  71
```

I'd like to drop the `c` level but keep all the other column names

```
   a     b    c1  c2
0  87    33   32  34
1  32    10   45  62
2  78    83   99  71
```

`df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)` works but the names of `a` and `b` disappear

```
              c1  c2
0  87    33   32  34
1  32    10   45  62
2  78    83   99  71
```

Comment: How do you get it? By `pivot_table` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to select second-level values if `c`:

```
df.columns = [col2 if col1 == 'c' else col1 for col1, col2 in df.columns]
print (df)
    a   b  c1  c2
0  87  33  32  34
1  32  10  45  62
2  78  83  99  71
```

---

Previous solutions for old pandas versions:

I think you can use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) + [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['a','b'])
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
    a   b  c1  c2
0  87  33  32  34
1  32  10  45  62
2  78  83  99  71
```

Another solution with select columns by `['c']`:

```
df = df.set_index(['a','b'])['c'].reset_index()
print (df)
    a   b  c1  c2
0  87  33  32  34
1  32  10  45  62
2  78  83  99  71
```

But if get it from `pivot_table` [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252078/2901002) is remove `[]` or add parameter `values='c'` if missing.

Comment: The second solution you posted worked for me.  The output for your first solution formatted differently for me than the output shown in the answer.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @jezrael: what versions of pandas does this work on? can you confirm it still works on 1.4, 1.5, 2.0?

Comment: @smci - You are right, it working for old pandas versions, so add to answer info about it with new solution working for all pandas versions

Comment: Can you state which versions? 1.4? 1.5? The new list comprehension is a bit hard to follow since it mixes variable names that happen to be col names. I'd write it as `df.columns = [col2 if col1 == 'c' else col1 for col1, col2 in df.columns]`

Comment: @smci - `Can you state which versions` - tested last 2 solutions in pandas 1.5 and failed, so create universal solution.

Comment: @smci - `df.columns = [col2 if col1 == 'c' else col1 for col1, col2 in df.columns]` - Super idea, I can add to answer.

Comment: Neat. You might also want to comment that `for clev1, clev2 in df.columns` is an iteration over the levels of a 2-level column multiindex.